# How would I useEffect with a whole function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement useEffects for the first time on my project but I'm not quite sure on how to follow from now on. I have a function that returns components based on a state.
Reduced version of it:

```
const list = () => {
return value.map((element, index) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.chosenExerciseContainer} key={generateKey(element)}>
      <View style={styles.chosenExercisesModal}>
        <Text>A lot of things here<Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
 });
};
```

And in my exported component I use it like this:

```
 (...)
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewModalBody}>
      {list()}
</ScrollView>
(...)
```

So, as soon as the state changes my function should change too and it should render again. The way it is now, its actually working but as I was going to throw the docs I realised that this could be a problem, so I'm trying to implement with useEffect.

As far I understood about the useEffect I should use "value" as the parameter to re-render, but I'm not sure what I should put inside the useEffect itself cause when I put the "list" like this:

```
  React.useEffect(()=>{
     const list = () => {
        (...)
      }
  },[value])
```

the component does not find it.

Inside the same screen I have a pop up with a Dropdown that changes the value.

```
<DropDownPicker
open={open}
value={value}
items={items}
setOpen={setOpen}
setValue={setValue}
setItems={setItems}
theme="LIGHT"
multiple={true}
mode="SIMPLE"
badgeDotColors={["black"]}
/>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how `useEffect` is meant to be applied here.  If `list` is a function that gets declared on the render of the component, it would use whatever state is available during that render.  What's the problem you're looking to solve here?

Comment: Adding to the above comment: What is value? I do not see it changing anywhere?

Comment: I would maybe change the way you are using the Components though instead Create a list Component then map that component into the DOM. Here is an example I just made someone else for Images: https://codesandbox.io/s/hoverimage-ldscek?file=/src/App.js:352-512. Might want to move this to a message room? If you want more help explaining this. I Don't think you want to use a useEffect in this case

Comment: @TusharShahi I edit the question, maybe it's more clear now.

Comment: @ColinHale I don't see that much difference in our code. If you would make your code dynamically with buttons  to remove elements from array or somewhat. Would you use useEffect? I'm askying this cause I may be misunderstanding the docs.

Comment: Yeah, I think in order to help you I would need to better understand how you think things work to clarify some stuff. Which would be out of the scope of this question which was why I was suggesting a message room. React may not know to update the Dom because list isn't based on state/will just trigger on first render. you could use a useEffect to reRun the list() function but I don't think thats best method I would change the way you are doing it and make list into a component and map it while managing the value in state so it would be value.map((el => <List stuff={el.stuff}/>))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use `useEffect` to just *declare a function*.  You probably don't need to make any changes at all in this code.

However, if you do want to declare a function which has dependencies on state and allow the framework to decide if that function should be re-created or not based on those dependencies, that's exactly what `useCallback` is for:

```
const list = useCallback(() => {
  return value.map((element, index) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.chosenExerciseContainer} key={generateKey(element)}>
        <View style={styles.chosenExercisesModal}>
          <Text>A lot of things here<Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  });
}, [value]);
```

The benefit here is essentially that the framework will skip the cost of creating a new function and re-use the previous one if the dependency array hasn't changed.  This can produce a performance improvement, but probably not a noticeable one.  Where this really becomes useful is when the function is a component prop.  For example:

```
<SomeComponent callback={list} />
```

Without `useCallback`, the function `list` "changes" on every render, even if nothing significant is actually different.  Which would cause `SomeComponent` to always re-render, and we don't know if that's an expensive operation or not.

But with `useCallback`, if nothing in the dependency array changes then `list` will be a reference to the same function instance as the previous render, so `SomeComponent` has no new props and can be more effectively memo-ized and optimized by the framework.

Comment: thanks.  I was not aware of the useCallback yet, will look into it. That's precisely what I was looking for.